# Theorem 4, Section 4.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation, divisibility

> If $f, d$ are polynomials over a field $F$ and $d$ is different from $0$ then there exist polynomials $q, r$ in $F[x]$ such that (i) $f = dq + r$. (ii) either $r=0$ or $\deg (r)\lt \deg (d)$.
>
> **Hoffman’s Proof:** If $f$ is $0$ or $\deg (f)\lt \deg (d)$ we may take $q=0$ and $r=f$. In case $f\neq 0$ and $\deg (f) \geq \deg (d)$, the preceding lemma shows we may choose a polynomial $g$ such that $f-dg=0$ or $\deg (f - dg) \lt \deg (f)$. If $f - dg \neq 0$ and $\deg (f- dg) \geq \deg (d)$ we choose a polynomial $h$ such that $(f-dg)- dh=0$ or $\deg [f-d(g+h)]\lt \deg(f-dg)$.
> Continuing this process as long as necessary, we ultimately obtain polynomials $q,r$ such that $r=0$ or $\deg (r)\lt deg (d)$,and $f=dq+r$.

**Que:** I don’t understand following step: If $f - dg \neq 0$ and $\deg (f- dg) \geq \deg (d)$ we choose a polynomial $h$ such that $(f-dg)- dh=0$ or $\deg [f-d(g+h)]\lt \deg(f-dg)$.
Continuing this process as long as necessary, we ultimately obtain polynomials $q,r$ such that $r=0$ or $\deg (r)\lt \deg (d)$,and $f=dq+r$.

---

In [this](https://youtu.be/Ate5sPNl6lo) video (time stamp 13:32) professor uses induction explicitly. Inductive hypothesis is suppose theorem holds for polynomial with degree $\lt n$. **Que:** I think, it is not the “usual” inductive hypothesis, i.e suppose $P(n-1)$ is true, for some $n$. I know there are different variation of mathematical induction. How to rigioursly proof present case of induction is correct?

**Edit:** I found [this](https://youtu.be/Nkiuq6eKEO4) amazing lecture on division algorithm for polynomial. The induction I was looking for is [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction).

Comment: Are we all supposed to be aware of the contents of the preceding lemma?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $g =\left(\frac{a_m}{b_n}\right)x^{m-n}$

Comment: This doesn’t really answer your question. But you might like [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4557580/what-are-some-slick-proofs-of-basic-algebraic-facts/4557716#4557716) of the division algorithm.

Comment: @Seeker fun fact: it is in my bookmark list since you wrote that post!

Comment: @user264745 That’s wonderful!