# Exercise 3, Section 4.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, proof-writing, ideals

**Definition:** Let $F$ be a field. An ideal in $F[x]$ is a subspace $M$ of $F[x]$ such that $f\cdot g\in M$, $\forall f\in F[x]$, $\forall g\in M$.

---

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over a field $F$. Show that the set of all polynomials $f$ in $F[x]$ such that $f(A)=0$ is an ideal.

**My attempt:** $A\in M_{n}(F)$. We need to show $M=\{f\in F[x]\ |\ f(A)=0\}$ is ideal in $F[x]$. Since $\dim (M_n(F))=n^2$, we have $I,A,A^2,…,A^{n^2}$ is linearly dependent. So $\exists c_0,c_1,…,c_{n^2}\in F$ such that $c_j\neq 0$, for some $j$ and $\sum_{i=0}^nc_i\cdot A^i=0$. Let $h=\sum_{i=0}^nc_i\cdot x^i\in f[x]\setminus \{0\}$. Then $h(A)=0$. So $h\in M$. Thus $M\neq \emptyset$. Let $f,g\in M$ and $c\in F$. By theorem 2 section 4.2, $(c\cdot f+g)(A)=c\cdot f(A)+g(A)=0$. Thus $c\cdot f+g\in M$. Hence $M$ is subspace of $F[x]$. Let $f\in F[x]$ and $g\in M$. By theorem 2 section 4.2, $f\cdot g(A)=f(A)\cdot g(A)=f(A)\cdot 0=0$. Thus $f\cdot g\in M$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: I just realised, property $M\neq \emptyset$ is equivalent to $0\in M$. By definition $0(\alpha )=0_V$, $\forall \alpha \in V$ ($V$ is linear algebra over $F$).

Comment: Yes, the zero polynomial is your friend.

Comment: Your proof is correct. As you have now realized, you can show $M$ is nonempty more quickly by using the zero polynomial. However your "longer" proof is still valuable as it shows that $M$ contains more than just the zero polynomial. After all, $\{0\}$ is an ideal; it could have been the case that $M = \{0\}$. You have shown that $M$ contains more than just $0$. I don't have this textbook, but I will suggest that you should remember this part of the proof, as there's a good chance it will be an exercise in the near future. :-)

Comment: @ZachTeitler I don’t know about exercise but this ideal is building block of minimal polynomial. Can you please help me with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4588636/861687) post (division algorithm for polynomial)? I have been stuck on that proof for long time.