# Theorem 2, Section 7.1 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, minimal-polynomials, companion-matrices

**Definition:** Suppose $p=x^k+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_i\cdot x^i\in F[x]$ is a monic polynomial. Then companion matrix of $p$ is $$\begin{bmatrix} & & & -a_0\\ 1& & &-a_1\\ &\ddots & & \vdots \\ & & 1& -a_{k-1}\\ \end{bmatrix}\in M_{k\times k}(F)$$

---

> If $U$ is a linear operator on the finite-dimensional space $W$, then $U$ has a cyclic vector if and only if there is some ordered basis for $W$ in which $U$ is represented by the companion matrix of the minimal polynomial
> for $U$.
>
> **Proof:** We have just observed that if $U$ has a cyclic vector, then there is such an ordered basis for $W$. Conversely, if we have some ordered basis $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_k\}$ for $W$ in which $U$ is represented by the companion matrix of its minimal polynomial, it is obvious that $\alpha_1$ is a cyclic vector for $U$.

**Que:** Let $\dim (W)=k$ and $U:W\to W$ be a linear operator. Let $m$ be minimal polynomial of $U$. Then $\deg (m)\leq k$. If $\deg (m)\lt k$, then matrix representation of $U$ with respect to some basis equal to companion matrix of $m$ don’t make sense, or is it?

Comment: What would the size of such a matrix be? Would that make sense?

Comment: @blargoner yes. Two different size matrix are equal. Can we fix definition of companion matrix so that “matrix representation of $U$ with respect to some basis equal to companion matrix of $m$” make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is well known, and quite obvious (look what $Q[M](e_1)$ is when $\deg(Q)\leq{k}$), that the minimal polynomial of a companion matrix$~M$ of $P$ is $P$ itself; in particular its degree equals the dimension of the vector space acted upon. Since the minimal polynomial is a property of a linear operator, it must be the same for any matrix of the operator, so by contrapositive, if the degree of the minimal polynomial of a linear operator is strictly less than the dimension of the space, it cannot have a companion matrix on any base.

The converse is also true: if the degree of the minimal polynomial of a linear operator equals the dimension of the space (so that the minimal polynomial itself coincides with the characteristic polynomial), then there exists a cyclic vector and so a basis for which the matrix it the companion matrix of the minimal polynomial. There are [several ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83052/18880) to characterise this situation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To be honest, I find your answer bit hard to follow. Is it really obvious that “minimal polynomial of a companion matrix $A$ of $p$ is $p$ itself”? Following is my proof of that claim: Let $U:F^k\to F^k$ defined by $[U]_B=A= \begin{bmatrix} & & & -a_0\\ 1& & & -a_1\\ &\ddots & & \vdots \\ & &1 & -a_{k-1}\\ \end{bmatrix}$, where $B=\{e_1,…,e_k\}$ is standard basis of $F^k$. Since $U(e_i)=e_{i+1}$, $\forall 1\leq i\leq k-1$, we have $B=\{e_1,U(e_1),…,U^{k-1}(e_1)\}$. So $F^k=\text{span}(B)=\text{span}(\{U^i(e_1)\mid i\geq 0\})=Z(e_1;U)$.

Comment: Since $U(e_k)=U^k(e_1)=-a_0e_1-…-a_{k-1}U^{k-1}(e_1)$ and by linear independence of $B$, we have $p$ is $U$-annihilator of $e_1$. By [theorem 1 section 7.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632463/861687), $p$ is minimal polynomial of $U$. Thus $p$ is minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: I added an answer at [that other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632463/861687), I hope this helps.